# Powershell v5 Get-Content (Chinese file names) amending. Filename/path not found or excluded

Tags: powershell, lua, chinese-locale

I have been trying to figure this out for the past hour. I have Chinese named filenames, however im using powershell version: `5.1.22000.653`. If I change it to test.lua it works just fine. However, upon running. it just tells me file is not able to be found or has been excluded. Only real work around I have found is amending the file name to temp 0-9 and re amending the file name afterwards manually as again not able able to read the Chinese file names. Only reason im using get child item for each is due to file names changing with -2 or -10 etc upon new updates. but the info inside said file names will always be static.

```
& "$env:windir\system32\chcp.com" 936
Get-ChildItem './*.lua' -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_) | ForEach  {$_ -Replace "Lua_Config_ZC_Out = true", "Lua_Config_ZC_Out = false" } | Set-Content $_
}
```

or

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
& "$env:windir\system32\chcp.com" 936
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *lua -rec 
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) 
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Lua_Config_ZC_Out = true", "Lua_Config_ZC_Out = false" } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Lua_Config_ZC_Open = 1", "Lua_Config_ZC_Open = 0" } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Config_State = 1", "Config_State = 0" } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Lua_Config = {xz = 50, xy = 10}", "Lua_Config = {xz = 65, xy = -1}" } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Lua_Config_HD_Re = 1", "Lua_Config_HD_Re = 0" } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "admin_config = false", "admin_skill = true" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
pause
```

same with both variations and just to test `Rename-Item -Path "E:\test\[副]混牢.lua" -NewName "0.lua"` result in Error:

```
PS E:\test> E:\test\Test.ps1
Active code page: 936

Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'E:\test\[副本]混沌地牢.lua' does not exist.
At E:\test\Test.ps1:4 char:1
+ Rename-Item -Path "E:\test\[副本]混沌地牢.lua" -NewName "0.lua"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Get-Content : An object at the specified path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::E:\test\[副]混牢.lua does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At E:\test\Test.ps1:6 char:6
+     (Get-Content $file.PSPath)
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 
Set-Content : An object at the specified path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::E:\test\[副]混牢.lua does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At E:\test\Test.ps1:14 char:5
+     Set-Content $file.PSPath
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Set-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
 
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Comment: Your source file names contain square brackets?  Use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` for that.

Comment: it does yes. So adding that did fix it thank you! Only thing i see now that might be an issue is the encoding is wrong causing the remarks on the file to be full Unicode symbols instead of Chinese. (correction:) before it was encoded as 'GB2312 Simplified' as default utf8 or ANSI causing it to be unreadable.

Comment: fixed... im dumb. 

```$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'*:Encoding' = 'Default'}```

Comment: Note that calling `chcp.com` from _inside_ PowerShell isn't effective, because .NET _caches_ encodings, but you can set both `[Console]::InputEncoding` and `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to achieve the same effect.